# PHP 7.4.x - Update SQLITE version used by PDO?

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

I have access to two different operating systems (Ubuntu and Raspberry OS) on two different environments: and I want them both to use the same (latest if possible) version of sqlite3.

| ARCH | OS | PHP | PDO Driver for SQLite 3.x |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x86 | Ubuntu | 7.4.3 | 3.31.1 |
| arm | Pi OS | 7.4.25 | 3.34.1 |

I'm new to PHP - so I'm not sure what the procedure is to update the PDO driver.
(I'm used to Tomcat; where you would generally drop a new JDBC JAR into the 'lib' directory - but not sure this is the same for PDO or not?)

Do I need to re-compile PHP in order to this? Or Can this be done entirely by configuration?

I am able to download and compile sqlite3 to generate the object file 'sqlite3.o' for the version of sqlite3 I need - but do I dynamically link to this etc? (if so how?).

Comment: These environments are very similar, both for PHP and for SQLite. Are there some breaking features that bother you? What motivates you to go beyond the normal updating process?

Comment: There are features in SQL which are only available in later versions. The 'UPDATE-FROM' feature (https://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html) is only available from 3.33.0 onwards for instance.

Comment: Could you also explain and/or point me at what is meant by 'normal updating process' - (I'm still getting to grips with PHP) - do you mean just waiting for the Linux Distribution to move through the versions of the various packages for instance?

Comment: Yes, that's the "normal" update process. I'm not using either OS's, but normally you update PHP through the OS. When you update the PHP version you should get a newer version of SQLite as well.

Comment: ok - thanks for that - just wanted to confirm my understanding.